# Python find if any(key: value) in of list of dicts using comprehension

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a situation where I am receiving a list of dicts and need to determine if the list is empty or if a certain value is present in a specific key:value pair in any of the dicts that may be received.
e.g.:

```
[{"blim": "nancy","blam": "x","blah": "1"}, {"blim": "bob","blam": "a","blah": "1"}, {"blim": "joe","blam": "p","blah": "0"}]
```

I am currently doing this using:

```
def foo(x, value):
    if not x: return True
    else:
        for y in x:
            if y["blah"] == value: return False
    return True

if foo(my_list, "0"):
    ...do truthy stuff here...
```

I would prefer to do something like:

```
if not x or not any y['blah'] == "0" in x:
    ...do truthy stuff here...
```

I have read everything I can find in the last 2 days about using comprehensions and all the suggestions that came up when I entered my title, but have found nothing that deals with this exactly.

I can get a nice generator

```
for y in x: False if any(y['blah']) == "0" else True
```

and I can get plenty of SyntaxErrors:

```
>>> x[y] for x[y]: if (x[y]['blah']=='0') in x
File "<stdin>", line 1
    x[y] for x[y]: if (x[y]['blah']=='0') in x
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> if (not x) or (y for y: any(y['blah']) in x == '0': print('stuff'))
File "<stdin>", line 1
    if (not x) or (y for y: any(y['blah']) in x == '0': print('stuff'))
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

...
```

I thought I might be close with:

```
>>> if not x or any(y['blah']) in x == '0': print('stuff')
...
>>>
```

but got no output even when my list of dicts was simply:

```
>>> x
[{'blah', '0'},{'blah', '0'}]
```

I think I've just fried my brain at this point and am missing something obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
any(D.get('blah') == '0' for D in L)
```

Comment: Thank you!!  This works nicely...  I will accept it as the answer when the timer is up. I have a few more minutes to wait.

Comment: It won't work if the element you're looking for is `None`, but that's what the third argument of `dict.get()` is for.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of get()...  The value for 'blah' will always be '1' or '0', so this is exactly what I needed.  Thanks again!